# integrate sine at denominator

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

This integral: $\int_{\pi/2}^0\frac{d\theta}{1-\gamma\sin 2\theta}$.

I tried $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ and $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$, but didn't succeed.
Is there any one can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what Spivak call last-resort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution. Use the substitution $ t = \tan{x/2} $. And Keep doing Algebra. there is an example in the wiki.

Comment: Thanks! It leads to $\int_\infty^0\frac{dt}{t^2-2\gamma t+1}$, which is not as difficult as the original one.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the tangent half-angle substitution is to put $e^{2 i \theta} = z$ and find an antiderivative in terms of $z$. A third option is to put $e^{2 i \theta} = z$ and recognize that you can write the integral as a contour integral over the unit circle.